# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Lifehacks has come to a close — your site's "graduation" election! The votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Ken Graham]

[image: Chenmunka]

[image: Glorfindel]

They will be replacing [the existing crew](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking BrettFromLA, who will be stepping down as moderator, after serving as a pro-tem since 2019:

[image: BrettFromLA]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5092875434983424).

Comment: (I could post another answer, but it would be merely repeating what my new colleagues already worded well enough. I felt it was better represented by an upvote ... Nevertheless, you all have my thanks!)

Comment: The pleasure, and benefit is ours. Also, a hearty and well deserved Thanks to BrettFromLA. We hope you won't be a stranger.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to everyone who took part, including all the candidates and all the voters.

I look forward to serving the community, and welcome aboard the new co-mods.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you to all who participated in the election, moderators and voters alike.

Congratulations Chenmunka and Glorfindel. Look forward to working together to make an awesome site together with all on the site.